# How to print a PDF in landscape mode

Tags: php, pdf, printing, landscape, tcpdf

I use TCPDF to generate an HTML table in PDF. I create my page in landscape mode in TCPDF :

```
$pdf->AddPage("L");
```

When I open the PDF it's OK.

But when I print it, I get a print in portrait mode. How can I force an impression in landscape mode without playing with the print modal windows that appears when I made `[Ctrl]+[P]` ?

Comment: The question you are asking is not clear. Landscape/portrait modes do not have a well defined meaning when it comes to *printing* a page on a piece of paper. Is what you really mean this: the page image is rotated by 90 or 270 degree in relation to the paper orientation? Or is it that your print *preview* window shows the page rotated by +/-90 degree?

Comment: The page image is rotated by 90 degree in relation to the paper orientation ;-)

Comment: So what's the result if you use `$pdf->AddPage("P");` in your code?

Comment: When I open my pdf, it's in portrait mode, same as a print.

Comment: Can you provide a (link to a) sample PDF page for more detailed inspection? What OS platform are you printing from, and which application?

Comment: Printing from a proper PDF reader, not your browser, may work better.

Answer (score 0):

The landscape/portrait mode on printer dialog is a feature of the printer settings , not the document (PDF in this example) and is controlled by the program that calls the printer, such as the web browser. You can't preconfigure this from PDF

And I think you can't set this from javascript on the web browser.